# Work legally using a haram tool ( Is the money made from it haram? )

Tags: halal-haram, money

lets say someone told me to make a wooden door for $100

i made it using haram bought tools (like hammer etc)

will my income be counted as haram or halal?

Comment: How can a hammer be haram?

Comment: @usman when its bought with haram money

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Since there is haram income used in the making of the door, the money you gain from the job will also be haram. This is because most things that have haram money involved then become haram.

Allah knows best